# mysql field updates

Tags: php, sql

This is a bit of an odd question, but I keep running into this with the devs. 
I'll make is simple

fields in car db
chev, dodge, chrystler, ford (and so forth)
I wrote php/mysql app to read and manipulate this data. But on rare occasions, more often than not these days, they go in and make changes to the fields
so now it may read
chevorlet, dodge,chrys, Ford <- caps

So here is one Idea I thought to combat this, it seems long winded, and am hoping for a better solution

make a config file with
`cars = array( 'chev' => 'chev', 'dodge'=>'dodge'` etc...

then if they change something, i can just edit the config to reflect that. so as with the above example
`cars = array( 'chev' => 'chevorlet', 'dodge'=>'dodge'` etc...

now all references to "chev" in my php will show chevorlet.

is this a good method or did I miss the mark completely. This is a huge DB, and I like the app I wrote, as I can manipulate it remotely as well. But these changes, mess up the source.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable solution to me, besides setting up different privileges for their mySQL user(s) as to lock them out from such updates.

Comment: Ideally you should validate your input before the database data is changed; comparing the value entered against a white list of car makes.

Comment: @BitwiseCreative if I could I would, but it is thier db, I just have access to use it as I like. There are like. It only happens on major updates, and not all fields get changed, but when it does, it is annoying. I thought there would be some faster way, but I do not mind storing the "original" fields in a config file, and just udate the ones they do, thus protecting my code from crashing :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enum data type to only allow specific case, or a trigger to force conversion to a consistent case. But the best solution would be to force a foreign key constraint against a table with the correct form of the data as the primary key. Make sure you use ascii bin comparisons.